# Discrepancy between KFlold on the one hand and KFold with shuffle=True and RepeatedKFold on the other hand in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am comparing KFlold and RepeatedKFold using sklearn version 0.22.
According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedKFold.html?highlight=repeatedkfold#sklearn.model_selection.RepeatedKFold): RepeatedKFold  "*Repeats K-Fold n times with different randomization in each repetition*." One would expect the results from running RepeatedKFold with only 1 repeat (n_repeats = 1) to be pretty much identical to KFold.

I ran a simple comparison:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, KFold, RepeatedKFold, RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn import metrics

X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)

classifier = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='elasticnet',  fit_intercept=True)
scorer = metrics.accuracy_score
results = []
n_splits = 5
kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X, y):
    x_train, y_train = X[train_index], y[train_index]
    x_test, y_test = X[test_index], y[test_index]
    classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
    results.append(scorer(y_test, classifier.predict(x_test)))
print ('KFold')
print('mean = ', np.mean(results))
print('std = ', np.std(results))
print()

results = []
n_repeats = 1
rkf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=n_splits, n_repeats = n_repeats)
for train_index, test_index in rkf.split(X, y):
    x_train, y_train = X[train_index], y[train_index]
    x_test, y_test = X[test_index], y[test_index]
    classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
    results.append(scorer(y_test, classifier.predict(x_test)))
print ('RepeatedKFold')
print('mean = ', np.mean(results))
print('std = ', np.std(results))
```

The output is

```
KFold
mean =  0.9082079851439182
std =  0.04697225962068869

RepeatedKFold
mean =  0.9493562364593006
std =  0.017732595698953055
```

I repeated this experiment enough times to see that the difference is statistically significant.

I was trying to read and reread the documentation to see if I'm missing something but to no avail.

Btw, the same holds true for StratifiedKFold and RepeatedStratifiedKFold:

```
StratifiedKFold
mean =  0.9159935004642525
std =  0.026687786392525545

RepeatedStratifiedKFold
mean =  0.9560476632621479
std =  0.014405630805910506
```

For this data set, StratifiedKFold agrees with KFold; RepeatedStratifiedKFold agrees with RepeatedSKFold.

> UPDATE
>   Following the suggestion from @Dan and @SergeyBushmanov, I included shuffle and random_state

```py
def run_nfold(X,y, classifier, scorer, cv,  n_repeats):
    results = []
    for n in range(n_repeats):
        for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X, y):
            x_train, y_train = X[train_index], y[train_index]
            x_test, y_test = X[test_index], y[test_index]
            classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
            results.append(scorer(y_test, classifier.predict(x_test)))    
    return results
kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits)
results_kf = run_nfold(X,y, classifier, scorer, kf, 10)
print('KFold mean = ', np.mean(results_kf))

kf_shuffle = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True, random_state = 11)
results_kf_shuffle = run_nfold(X,y, classifier, scorer, kf_shuffle, 10)
print('KFold Shuffled mean = ', np.mean(results_kf_shuffle))

rkf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=n_splits, n_repeats = n_repeats, random_state = 111)
results_kf_repeated = run_nfold(X,y, classifier, scorer, rkf, 10)
print('RepeatedKFold mean = ', np.mean(results_kf_repeated)
```

produces

```
KFold mean =  0.9119255648406066
KFold Shuffled mean =  0.9505304859176724
RepeatedKFold mean =  0.950754100897555
```

Moreover, using Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:

```py
print ('Compare KFold with KFold shuffled results')
ks_2samp(results_kf, results_kf_shuffle)
print ('Compare RepeatedKFold with KFold shuffled results')
ks_2samp(results_kf_repeated, results_kf_shuffle)
```

shows that KFold shuffled and RepeatedKFold (which looks it is is shuffled by default, you are right @Dan) are statistically the same, whereas the default non-shuffled KFold produces statistically significant lower result:

```
Compare KFold with KFold shuffled results
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.66, pvalue=1.3182765881237494e-10)

Compare RepeatedKFold with KFold shuffled results
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.14, pvalue=0.7166468440414822)
```

Now, note that I used **different** random_state for KFold and RepeatedKFold. So, the answer, or rather the partial answer, is that the difference in results is due to shuffling vs non-shuffling. Which makes sense, since using different random_state can change the exact split, and it shouldn't change the statistical properties, like the mean of multiple runs.

I'm now confused by why shuffling causes this effect. I've changed the title of the question to reflect this confusion ( I hope it doesn't break any stackoverflow rules, but I don't want to create another question).

> UPDATE
>   I agree with  @SergeyBushmanov's suggestion. 
>   I posted it as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496628/difference-between-sklearn-kflold-with-and-without-using-shuffle)

Comment: Did you try giving them both the same `random_state` seed?

Comment: No, I  hadn't. I tried now and I'm getting a warning "FutureWarning: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. This will raise an error in 0.24. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True."

Comment: So I would guess that RepeatedKFold has shuffle forced to True, so I would suggest the fairest test would be to set the same random_state for each and to set `shuffle=True` for `Kfold`. In your repeated experiments, did you get the same result for `KFold` each time and a different result for `RepeatedKFold`?

Comment: @DavidMakovoz `RepeatedKFold` uses `KFold` underneath to generate folds. See the link to the code below in my answer. They are producing the same splits as long as `random_seed` is the same.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov, yes, I implemented it above. The question now is why the default unshuffled KFold produces results that are statistically significantly different  than shuffled KFold.

Comment: Given your last comment I think you have to make it clearer what is your problem. Maybe open another question.

Comment: On a side note to your original question. Expecting different kinds of samplings from the same distribution to have the same σ or μ is OK. It's called Central Limit Theorem. You can expect so with the size of original population and number of experiments increasing. To expect the same on top of unknown ML algo is an overstatement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make `RepeatedKFold` results similar to `KFold` you have to:

```
np.random.seed(42)
n = np.random.choice([0,1],10,p=[.5,.5])
kf = KFold(2,shuffle=True, random_state=42)
list(kf.split(n))
[(array([2, 3, 4, 6, 9]), array([0, 1, 5, 7, 8])),
 (array([0, 1, 5, 7, 8]), array([2, 3, 4, 6, 9]))]
```

```
kfr = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=2, n_repeats=1, random_state=42)
list(kfr.split(n))
[(array([2, 3, 4, 6, 9]), array([0, 1, 5, 7, 8])),
 (array([0, 1, 5, 7, 8]), array([2, 3, 4, 6, 9]))]
```

`RepeatedKFold` [uses](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L1182) `KFold` to generate folds, you only need to make it sure both have similar `random_state`.