# Difference between sklearn KFold with and without using shuffle

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am working with `KFlold` using sklearn version 0.22. It has a parameter `shuffle`.
According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html?highlight=kfold#sklearn.model_selection.KFold)

> shuffle boolean, optional Whether to shuffle the data before splitting
>   into batches.

I ran a simple comparison of using `KFold` with `shuffle` set to `False` (default) and `True`:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, KFold, RepeatedKFold, RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn import metrics

X, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
def run_nfold(X,y, classifier, scorer, cv,  n_repeats):
    results = []
    for n in range(n_repeats):
        for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X, y):
            x_train, y_train = X[train_index], y[train_index]
            x_test, y_test = X[test_index], y[test_index]
            classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
            results.append(scorer(y_test, classifier.predict(x_test)))    
    return results

classifier = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='elasticnet',  fit_intercept=True)
scorer = metrics.accuracy_score
n_splits = 5
kf = KFold(n_splits=n_splits)
results_kf = run_nfold(X,y, classifier, scorer, kf, 10)
print('KFold mean = ', np.mean(results_kf))

kf_shuffle = KFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True, random_state = 11)
results_kf_shuffle = run_nfold(X,y, classifier, scorer, kf_shuffle, 10)
print('KFold Shuffled mean = ', np.mean(results_kf_shuffle))
```

produces

```
KFold mean =  0.9119255648406066
KFold Shuffled mean =  0.9505304859176724
```

Using Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:

```py
print ('Compare KFold with KFold shuffled results')
ks_2samp(results_kf, results_kf_shuffle)
```

shows the default non-shuffled `KFold` produces statistically significant lower results than the shuffled `KFold`:

```
Compare KFold with KFold shuffled results
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.66, pvalue=1.3182765881237494e-10)
```

I don't understand the difference between the shuffling vs non-shuffling results, why does it change the distribution of the output so drastically.

Comment: I imagine that there's some pattern in the default order of the dataset, which causes the train/test sets to be more different from each other if you don't shuffle (think splitting `a = [0,1,2,5,6,7]` in two). Since the classifier is not linear, this can cause the distribution of predictions to be different.

Comment: What you're trying to prove is validity of Central Limit Theorem after applying ML algo. There is no evidence, or at least I am unaware of it, that this should hold true.

Comment: As a different perspective, `SGD` is a greedy algo, so the results will differ with the order of data you feed in.